# Sending Scheduled Text message

Tags: time-dependent-workflow, visual-flows, recordtriggeredflow, scheduled-flow

I created a flow where I am sending a text message to the sales rep when certain criteria's are met on the custom object. for example

- If the task is open for a particular category send a text to remind the sales rep to close the task
- For sending the text message I used digital engagement messaging channels.
- I was able to send text successfully but now the users want to send the text message everyday at 9 am EST until the rep close the task.

So it will be like a daily reminder text message with the record link. I am not sure how to send this reminder text everyday.

Is it possible from scheduled flows? I don't know how to build this criteria from scheduled flows. Please guide. Thanks!

Comment: Scheduled flows? YES, they would run at 0900 every day.  Query on open Tasks for category X